# Adding a button on web debug tool bar symfony2 createbundle

Tags: symfony

I want to add a new button on the top web debug toolbar. I would be using that button to create a copy of that particular page and save it with another name.

I have been searching but couldnt find a solution. It seems that its possible but i haven't had any success yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to do with that "button" and why you need it, but it is written in the doku, how the create a custom datacollector

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html